# Add Tax to user input in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, razor

How can I add a tax value to user input in Razorview

This is current code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @{
            double tax = 12.5;
        }

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price * tax, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>
</div>
```

Yet this is not working, please help me in this

Comment: Actually when I run this code the app crashes - so I wanted help with if I was typing something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a Property in my model that returns the Price including tax.

```
public class model
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceWithTax
    {
        get
        {
            return Price * 1.125m;
        }
    }
}
```